# prevent multiple upvote Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To begin sorry for my English.

I made some search about this problem, but nothing works for me.

My problem is simple : 

I have an upvote system, where users can upvote (like Stackoverflow). But the problem is that users can upvote multiple times (and it's not very well ..). 

I tried to make a button with ng-disabled, but if i do this, users can only vote one time for all the posts (I mean if they upvoted "Post A", they can't upvote "Post B").

Here is my controller function :

```
$scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
        posts.upvote(post);
    };
```

Here is my factory function :

```
o.upvote = function(post){
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote', null, {
        headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
        post.upvotes += 1;
    });
};
```

And here the html :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
```

If someone could help me it would be great ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm sure you know this already, but just a reminder: you can't prevent users from voting multiple times using only Angular, no matter what you do. You'll have to add extra checks to the server if you want to prevent it completely.

Comment: you would have to do it at back-end, maybe a mapping table mapping user with the Question asked . Wheneva a user upvotes a post in a Question details you would save the user and question id in the mapping table and you would have a $scope variable which would set it true or false and again which on load of the question would check the with the mapping table  whether the record exists in the mapping table and set the variable true or false

Comment: I'm not angular-friedly yet, I thought it was possible by this way, and I lost lot of time.. I should have asked before. Thanks for your help, I will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use `button` or `input` instead of `span`. Because `disabled` does not work in a `span`.

```
<button id="{{ post._id + 'upvote' }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></button>
```

Then set `disabled` attribute of your upvote `button` true after the upvote action.

```
o.upvote = function(post){
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/upvote', null, {
        headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
    }).success(function(data){
        post.upvotes += 1;
        angular.element(document.getElementById(post._id + 'upvote' ))[0].disabled = true;
    });
};
```

Comment: `ng-disabled` would not work on `span`, it only works on input element..make it button would work

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my answer, can you help me check it is right or not

Comment: Disabled attributes on spans don't do anything. It doesn't make any difference if you use `ng-disabled` or `.disabled = true`.

Comment: Element Id's must be unique.  It should be something like `<input id="{{ post._id + 'upvoteInput' }}"`  Then in the function, search for it the same way:  `document.getElementById(post._id + 'upvoteInput')`

Comment: The answer will be fine step by step. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I just tried your solution, and it works !! Thanks you so much ! But, for people who has the same problem, if user refresh the page, he could upvote for the same post again. In my case, it's ok for the moment. 
Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an architectural question than it is javascript/angularjs question.  There are many ways to do this.  But the idea is to store in database and persist upvote information, otherwise users can just refresh the page and upvote again.

Most direct solution is:  You have to store your vote information on the backend at the user level.  When you query the user information, store a list of up-voted posts like this:

**`myDataService` should look like this:**

```
angular.module("app", []).service("myDataService", ["$http","$q","$rootScope", function myDataService($http, $q, $rootScope) {
    var myDataService = this;

    myDataService.getPostsUpvoted = function(userId) {
        var defer = $q.defer();

        //here you format your payload to deliver userId to the api backend
        var payload = { userId: userId };

        //your api backend 'getpostsupvoted' should accept a userId, then in return it should
        //deliver a list of posts upvoted by that user
        $http.post("/api/getpostsupvoted", payload).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //call success
            defer.resolve(data);
        }, function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //an error occurred
            defer.reject(data);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }

    return myDataService;
})];
```

Then, this is how you'll use the service in your controller.

```
//inject scope and myDataservice into controller
angular.module("app", []).controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", "myDataService", function($scope, myDataService) {

    //create a new array to hold a list of upvotes
    $scope.user.upVoted = [];
    myDataService.getPostsUpvoted($scope.user.id).then(function(data) {
        //set upvoted array to data
        $scope.user.upVoted = data;
    }, function(error) {
        //blah an error occurred
    });

})];
```

In your controller, provide a function to check if a post has already been upvoted.

```
$scope.IsUpvotedAlready = function(postId) {

    if($scope.user.upVoted.indexOf(postId) > -1)
        return true;

    return false;

}
```

You'll also have to push the post._id to the upVoted array and keep it there.

```
$scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {

    //check if it's already been upvoted, then do nothing
    if($scope.user.upVotes.indexOf(post._id) > -1)
        return;

    posts.upvote(post);

    $scope.user.upVoted.push(post._id);
};
```

Then, in your ng-repeat directive where you display the post, check if the list of upvotes contain the post._id.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <div ng-if="IsUpvotedAlready(post._id)">
        <!-- display something since already upvoted !-->
    </div>
    {{ post }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I can't try it now but it seems to be fine ! I will test tomorrow.

Comment: There is just one thing that I'm not sure, do I have do insert your first block code into my factory ?

Answer (score 1):

In the template when you are iterating the posts, have a flag for each post which identifies if it has been upvoted or not.

In the `upvote` function mark that flag as true and use it in the `ng-disabled` directive like this :

```
ng-disabled={{post.isUpvoted}}
```

Comment: Thanks to answering, I will try tomorrow